# HTML5 canvas and drawImage

Tags: html, canvas

Im building a diagram editor, and it works fine, drag & drop, copy and past everything works fine. But Im having som trouble with images. I have a render() function that runs everytime somthing changes. Inside the render function i call on the appendImg code. This works perfekt the first time the render is run. But the next time, and I get into the else code block the images are not beeing renderd on the canvas. I have this if.else logic her because if I run the img.onload everytime somthing changes the image is loaded every time, and i get a lot of flickering on the screen.
As far as I can se the drawImage dosent like it when the img obj has been stored withing the array, and I cant seem to get my head around it.

```
var images = []; //An array where images are stored.

appendImg = function(inx, url, x, y, w, h) {

  if (!images[inx]) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function()
    {
        dg_context.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
        images[inx] = img;
    }
    img.src = url;
  }else{
    var img = images[inx];
    console.log(img);
    dg_context.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing inx as a property of img so inx can be remembered inside onload:

```
var images = []; //An array where images are stored.

appendImg = function(inx, url, x, y, w, h) {

  if (!images[inx]) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function()
    {
        dg_context.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
        images[img.index] = img;
    }
    img.index=inx;
    img.src = url;
  }else{
    var img = images[inx];
    console.log(img);
    dg_context.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, that is'nt it(I did try it). But as I said: the images are loaded on the first load, so it work inside .onload. The problem is that is seems like the image is'nt loaded when im in the else code block. I did a console.log(img), and it is printing a <img> tag with the currekt url. But the img just issent drawn on the last drawImage